# Error in running mincemeat

Tags: python, mapreduce, mincemeat

I'm getting an error while running mincemeat. The code runs ok in octo.py. I'm not putting the code as it is for a coursera assignment but would really prefer mincemeat. The error is as below:

```
C:\Python27>python mincemeat.py -p changeme localhost

C:\Python27>python mincemeat.py -v changeme localhost
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mincemeat.py", line 376, in <module>
    run_client()
  File "mincemeat.py", line 372, in run_client
    client.conn(args[0], options.port)
  File "mincemeat.py", line 149, in conn
    self.connect((server, port))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\asyncore.py", line 347, in connect
    err = self.socket.connect_ex(address)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\socket.py", line 224, in meth
    return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
socket.gaierror: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed

C:\Python27>ping localhost

Pinging anand [::1] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from ::1: time<1ms
Reply from ::1: time<1ms
Reply from ::1: time<1ms
Reply from ::1: time<1ms

Ping statistics for ::1:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 0ms, Maximum = 0ms, Average = 0ms
```

Comment: You used -v instead of -p.  It's not picking up localhost as the hostname

Comment: but as per mincemeat code -v is verbose. with -p the server terminates without showing a error

Comment: Then you need both -v and -p.

Answer (score 0):

mincemeat.py is terminating because it does not have any work to do.  Follow the example at https://github.com/michaelfairley/mincemeatpy.  You need to run your mapreduce script then mincemeat.py.